# Option does not appear in config.h

Tags: c, makefile, autoconf

I want to include an own option to Bochs. My part of the configure.in:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING(for my feature)
AC_ARG_ENABLE(my_feature,
  AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-my_feature], [compile in support for my_feature (no)]),
  [if test "$enableval" = yes; then
    AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)
    AC_DEFINE(BX_SUPPORT_MY_FEATURE, 1)
   else
    AC_MSG_RESULT(no)
    AC_DEFINE(BX_SUPPORT_MY_FEATURE, 0)
   fi
   ],
  [
    AC_MSG_RESULT(no)
    AC_DEFINE(BX_SUPPORT_MY_FEATURE, 0)
    ]
  )
```

Then I build a configure file with autoconf.
When I have a look into the config.log, there the

```
#define BX_SUPPORT_MY_FEATURE 1
```

line appears. But in the config.h it does not appear.
How to get this macro into config.h?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you have a line `#undef BX_SUPPORT_MY_FEATURE` in your `config.h.in`?

Comment: No, there is nothing like that.

Comment: Please add one and try again.

Comment: Ah thanks! That worked for me! Seems that I don't really understand autotools... :(

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to manually edit `config.h.in` - just run [autoheader](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#autoheader-Invocation).